# Outputting a double in exponential notation

Tags: c#

I am converting a VB6 application to C#. My C# code is:

```
double a = 0.1345;
double b = 56.0;
double c = 40574.0;
double d = a * (b / c);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

as per VB the above code should return `1.856361216542613e-4`

but my application is returning `0.000185636121654261`.

I need the value as it is having `e` notation.

Answer (score 3):

You just nedd to use `ToString()` with proper format:

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("e"));
```

More formats on: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**
To increase a precion, you need to specify it after `e`:

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("e16"));
//1.8563612165426135e-004
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to get rid of `00` before `4` in exponent. Here is explanation:

> The case of the format specifier indicates whether to prefix the
>   exponent with an "E" or an "e". **The exponent always consists of a plus
>   or minus sign and a minimum of three digits**. The exponent is padded
>   with zeros to meet this minimum, if required.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT2:**
In order to get rid of padding in exponent, you could write the following format:

```
 Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.##############e+0"));
```

Comment: "e" returned 1.856361e-004, "E" 1.856361E-004. 
I need complete 1.856361216542613e-4!! possible..?

Comment: thankyou. so, shall i replace "004" with "4". is this the only way?

Comment: lets say d = 1.25;
now "0.##############e+0" wont work nor "e16", i will get 1.35e+0 !!
i dont need "e" in normal cases. i think u got my point.

Comment: @HakunaMatata Check [this MSDN page on custom numeric format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info about that. You can find the `e+0` format there. Not sure why the example doesn't work for you.